# Missing JS code for custom stripe donation form

Tags: forms, stripe-payments, donations

I'm using formspree.io stripe donation form. Works fine but the amount is hardcoded and the visitor can't change it. I need to be able to provide a custom amount. Stripe gave me the html for the custom amount but now I need the js code and I haven't been able to spot the code in stripe doc. Anyone has a clue about that js code that will bypass the hardcoded amount?

- formspree: https://formspree.io/blog/custom-payment-stripe/
- my page: https://soundsirius.digitalpress.blog/donation/

Comment: Formspree appears to use a unique endpoint for each Amount you want to charge, so you'd need to set up different endpoints for different amounts (nothing you modify on the frontend/JS will change this, by the look of it). You likely should ask Formspring directly and see if they have an offering with a custom amount per call.

Comment: they are a bit slow to answer :)